# php (if) condition is not working in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use DB;
    use App\Models\User;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Redirect;

    class Insertlikes extends Controller
    {
        public function insertlikesform()
        {
            return view('dashboard');
        }
      
        public function insertlike(Request $request)
        {
          $book_id = $request->input('book_id');
          $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
          $user_name = Auth::user()->name;
          if(DB::select("select count(*) from likesrate where user_id='$user_id' and book_id='$book_id'")==0)
          {
            DB::insert('insert into likesrate (book_id,user_id,user_name) values(?,?,?)',[$book_id,$user_id,$user_name]);
          }
          else if(DB::select("select count(*) from likesrate where user_id='$user_id' and book_id='$book_id'")>0)
          {
            DB::delete("delete from likesrate where user_id='$user_id' and book_id='$book_id'");
          }
          return \Redirect::back();
        }
    }
```

I have given a condition inside that if statement, but I don't why is not working but else if statement is working fine. I want to delete a data if it already exists and insert a data if it does not exist. May I know some proper solution for this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try checking the output of your `DB::select(...)` statements and verify that they contain what you expect.

Comment: From [Running Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#running-queries): "The select method will always return an array of results."

Comment: type juggling ... `select` isn't returning integers it is returning an array of potential results ...`[] == 0` is `false` but `[] > 0` is `true`

Answer (score 2):

There is the problime:

```
if(DB::select("select count(*) from likesrate where user_id='$user_id' and book_id='$book_id'")==0)
```

The query does not return an integer to compare it with `0`.

What you can do is something like:

```
$likes_count = DB::table("likesrate")->where("user_id", $user_id)->where("book_id", $book_id)->count();

if($likes_count == 0){
    // blah blah blah
```